# Grails, Delete-button on same form as Update in edit-view

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I'm trying to add a delete-button to my edit-form but have not found anything that works. Suggestions I've seen, is using AJAX, but I don't know how to make it.

I don't like to make another form below the existing one for "update" but it looks impossible to have the delete-button to the right of the update-button.
Any one having an idea...?

I tested this:

```
            $( document ).ready( function() {
                $('#delete_prod').on('click',function(event) {
                    alert('DELETE!!!');
                    var id=$(this).data('id');
                    var url="${createLink(controller: 'prodBuffer',action:'delete')}/"+id
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#results').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script> 

<span id="delete_prod" data-id="1">Delete<span>
```

But the alert will not be hit.

Comment: line above the alert should be like `$('#delete_prod').on('click',function(event) {`

Answer (score 0):

A button within existing form will act as submit button, you can look into `<g:actionSubmit` and submit it as a delete action that you then control in the contorller or use something like this - make something behave as a button then action it using ajax

```
<span id="deleteButton" data-id="${instance.id}">Delete<span>

<script>
$('#deleteButton').on('click',function() {
   var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
  var url="${createLink(controller: 'controller',action:'delete')}/"+id
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
                $('#results').html(data);
            }
        });
})
<script>
```

Comment: I tested your code and then changed it a couple of times but, not even the alert will be executed. I added the code into my question. I also moved the gsp-code to different places but nothing happens. I tested removing all code except the alert-call without success. That's strange as I already got some other javascript working.

Comment: there was as typo in script which is now fixed it may be that you have something else on the page with delete id hence renamed to deleteButton

Comment: also note if it is an iteration then change `id="deleteButton"` to `class="deletButton"` and change js from `$('#deleteButton')` to `$('.deleteButton') .on..` you can only have 1 id instance per page changing to class will work through all iterations of deleteButton on html page and assign correct value based on `$(this)`

Comment: Something had changed in my old scripts so when I removed one script that I didn't need any longer your script started to respond but I had to change type from "post" to "delete" otherwise I got "Method not allowed". As I used the "Generate all to get my initial controller and view I have the delete action complete with "redirect" but in this case, redirect does not work. So what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button group (bootstrap) and a single javascript ajax call to handle both buttons. We're using the id of the button to distinguish which action to call.

Your form will be different with regard to the data present, I've just used a hidden id field as an example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '.itemAction' ).click(function (event) {
            if ( confirm( 'Are you sure?' )) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/prodBuffer/" + this.id,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $( '#myForm' ).serialize(),
                    success: function ( data ) {
                        $( '#resultdiv' ).html( 'Success' );
                        window.setTimeout( function(){ location = '/prodBuffer/index' }, 2000 )
                    },
                    error: function(j, status, eThrown) { console.log( 'Error ' + eThrown ) },
                    complete: function() { console.log( 'Complete' ) }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="resultdiv"></div>

<g:form name="myForm">

    <g:hiddenField name="id" value="1" />

    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" name="myUpdate" id="myUpdate" value="Update" class="itemAction btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <button type="button" name="myDelete" id="myDelete" value="Delete" class="itemAction btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>

</g:form>
```

Controller:

```
def myUpdate() {
    myService.update( params )
    render (['success'] as JSON )
}

def myDelete() {
    myService.delete( params )
    render (['success'] as JSON )
}
```

Comment: It looks nice but it does not call the action, the confirm dialog occurs but neither the update nor the delete actions are called. I also think that I need to change the type from post to delete when calling the delete action.

Comment: I have it working here, are you using scaffolding and default controller actions? Maybe change the name and id in button to myUpdate and myDelete and define same actions, note I changed the g:form from id to name to assist with the serializing of data to controller. Also check the javascript console to see what, if any errors you are receiving, ffox & chrome right click > inspect > console tab

Comment: Ok, that worked. Now the actions is called and it is a good idea to use a service here as I need to do more than just delete this post. But I need to redirect to another view after delete, is that possible in the javascript or here? It didn't work in the other solutions I tried.

Comment: Yes sure, you can wait a bit to show your success message then change location, I've updated answer to go to prodBuffer/index after success

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

- Change your span to an `<a>` tag. It might be easier to handle the
  different states it has, and easier to style if you use bootstrap or
  similar frameworks.

Now to the code:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <!-- your form fields here-->

    <div>
        <button type="submit">My update button</button> <!-- The normal buttons you´d use-->
        <a href="${createLink(controller: 'prodBuffer', action: 'delete', id: yourDomainId)}" class="button delete-button">Delete button</a>  <!-- your actual delete button -->
    </div>

</form>

<div id="results"></div>
```

The html is quite simple and quite similar to what you might have. The difference being that I would prefer to reference my `<a>` via class instead of ID. Using `<a>` instead of `<span>` might make your code more manageable.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.delete-button').on('click', function(event){                
                event.preventDefault();  //1
                var deleteTarget = $(this).prop('href'); //2            

                if(confirm("Are you sure?")){ //3
                    $.post( //4
                        deleteTarget, 
                        function successhandler(responseData){
                            $('#results').html(responseData);
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

As for the javascript, the following applies:

1. Prevent the default action for your `<a>`
2. Obtain the href of the clicked link
3. Add a confirmation, just in case
4. Send your data and manage your response

Comment: Looks promising but I get some error when I render the view. See my comment in your answer.

Comment: in the code you sent me you lave the following code : `<a href="${createLink(controller: 'prodBuffer', action: 'delete', id: ${this.prodBuffer?.id})}" class="button delete-button">Delete button</a>  <!-- your actual delete button -->` In the code you sent the problem is the `id: ${this.prodBuffer?.id}` part. It should be `href="${createLink(controller: 'prodBuffer', action: 'delete', id:this.prodBuffer?.id)}". Since your createLink function is inside an `"${}"` anything inside it is direct code, no `${}` needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to use Ajax for deletion, you can make a Delete button and code on your Domain's show page and controller (for show) like below which also give you a confirm alert. this call the delete method. Have a look.

[image]
[image]

### Show page Code (show.gsp)

```
        <g:form>
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${prodBufferInstance?.id}" />
                <g:link class="edit" action="edit" id="${prodBufferInstance?.id}"><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link>
                <g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
```

### Controller Code (for show page)

```
    def show(Long id) {
      def prodBufferIns = ProdBuffer.get(id)
       if (!prodBufferIns) {
         flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'prodBufferIns.label', default: 'CustMeterReadingTemp'), id])
         redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [prodBufferInstance: prodBufferIns]
}
```

### Controller Code (Delete method)

```
def delete(Long id) {
    def prodBufferIns= ProdBuffer.get(id)
    if (!prodBufferIns) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'prodBuffer.label', default: 'prodBuffer'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    try {
        prodBufferIns.delete(flush: true)

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'prodBuffer.label', default: 'prodBuffer'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'prodBuffer.label', default: 'prodBuffer'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
```